# Alter Query To Change Date Format

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i use the alter query to change a DATE format in mysql
    for example

```
ALTER table userdata ADD column DateofBirth DATE SET = '%d-%m-%Y';
```

I tried this and it didnt work.

Comment: You need a `update` statement

Comment: *it didn't work* is not a  useful problem description. How **specifically** did it **not work**? If you can't be bothered to explain the problem you're having, why should we bother to try to help you?

Comment: firstly i added the new column using this ; ALTER table userdata ADD column DateofBirth DATE  and then i tried to change the format using this query; UPDATE userdata SET DateofBirth = date_format(now(),'%DD/%MM/%YYY');

Comment: And each time i try to insert a date value, the default format still remains,it dosen't adopt the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are stored in column with type DATE. You can set date format in SELECT query:
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateofBirth ,'%d-%m-%Y') AS DateofBirth FROM userdata;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "date format" specified with the `DATE` datatype.  It's not possible to specify a format with the column definition.

MySQL does provide a couple of useful functions... `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` that convert between `DATE` and string representations, in a variety of formats.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, you need a `update` statement

```
Update userdata set DateofBirth = DATE_FORMAT(DateofBirth ,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

But it is better to store dates in `DATE` datatype